# Plant Identification: Is this lemon balm?

Tags: plant-identification

It has the characteristics of lemon balm / mint, with square stems, but it doesn't have the lemon / mint smell. Also, its leaves seem to be more rounded, where lemon balm leaves have more of a pointed tip.

[image]

Comment: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/ is also a very good source for identifying plants.  If you move this question to that stack, please include the location of the plant.

Answer (score -2):

This looks like American Cornmint to me.  If you still have access to the plant, pinch one of the leaves and you should be able to smell if it is a mint or lemon balm.

Comment: Can you add a bit more detail? Like how you know it's possibly american cornmint?

Comment: Simply by appearance and my familiarity with the plant.

Comment: As it stands this is more of a comment, and may get downvoted or deleted.

Comment: No problem.  I still believe what I provided is a useful answer.